# How to get gameobject position from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-engine

I have a bullet that touches the enemy.
Then a text appears, which, thanks to the animation, shows how much life was taken from the enemy.

When I throw the prefab of that text on the enemy, so that the texts appear on the enemy via Instantiate, when the enemy destroys, the texts are quickly lost along with it.

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        
        if (FlyingTextPrefab)
        {
            ShowFlyingText();
        } 

        Destroy(collision.gameObject);

    }
   
     
}
void ShowFlyingText()
{
    var go = Instantiate(FlyingTextPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
    go.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshPro>().text = demage.ToString();
}
```

I moved Instantiate to another code to work independently of the enemy, but now I can not make the text appear from the position of the enemy.

**Enemy Code**

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("flyingText", "true");
        
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);

    }

}
```

**Text Instantiate**

```
void Update()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("flyingText") == "true")
    {
        ShowFlyingText();
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("flyingText", "false");
    }
}
void ShowFlyingText()
{
    var go = Instantiate(FlyingTextPrefab, Enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform); // how to get Enemy positions, its dont works normally
    go.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshPro>().text = 50.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And why not simply **not** spawn it as child of the enemy but still at its position:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        
        if (FlyingTextPrefab)
        {
            ShowFlyingText();
        } 

        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }    
}

void ShowFlyingText()
{
    var go = Instantiate(FlyingTextPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    go.GetComponent<TMPro.TextMeshPro>().text = demage.ToString();
}
```

without passing in the `transform` as the parameter `parent`.

> Parent that will be assigned to the new object.

Comment: its worked, but text position y dont changes with enemy

Answer (score 0):

Don't spawn the text as child to the enemy
Instead of typing

```
var go = Instantiate(FlyingTextPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

Type

```
 var go = Instantiate(FlyingTextPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

In this way the text will instantiated in the world instead of instantiated as child to the enemy object